# error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol linker can't find dll

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll, gtk

This is my first question, and yes it has been asked many times over on this site. I've looked through every previous question before and either the answer isn't their or i'm to tired to see it.

I've been trying for days now to implement a GTK+ project in Visual Studios 2010 and keep getting stumped with a main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _gtk_init_abi_check referenced in function _main (as well as a few other functions). I've tried multiple version 3.x(32b, and 64) and 2.x(32b,64b) but am currently trying to use GTK vs 2 32 bit since it is the most supported branch. I've linked the header files, the library files, and have an envirnment path variable = PATH=$(ProjectDir)GTK\bin.

When I run Verbose I get Searching libraries. *{full path} is the actual path.
1>      Searching {full path}\GTK\lib\gtk-win32-2.0.lib:
and so on for all the GTK libraries so i'm guessing that the .dll's are not being found.
The other dependence are however being found
Found _mainCRTStartup
1>          Loaded MSVCRTD.lib(crtexe.obj)

From what I've read the path variable should have allowed the .dll's to be found. I've thrown the dll everywhere I thought the linker could look. In the Resource file, beside the .cpp, in the debug folder and nothings worked.

My current code is

```
#include <gtk\gtk.h>
int main (int argc, char *argv[]){

    GtkWidget *window;

    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);
    /*
    window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "Hello World");
    gtk_widget_show (window);


    gtk_main (); 
    */
    return 0;
}
```

Why isn't the Linker finding the functions? 
I should also note that I've tried linking the libraries directly through the command line as well as pragma comment with out success. Its the GTK projects so the binaries should be well programmed. Also I've compiled multiple times as suggested in a previous thread. So what am I missing in terms of linker environment stuff? I should note that this is my first time setting up dll's for a project so it could be a very noobish mistake.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a link-time issue and has nothing to do with missing DLL's. Chances are you're linking to release versions of the libraries when you should be linking to debug versions (if available).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure required libraries are listed in "Additional Dependencies" field in the Input property page of the Linker folder in project's Property Pages dialog box.

Secondly, set "No Common Language Runtime support" for your project via "Project | Properties | Configuration Properties | General" folder.